# How to Populate an email recipient depending on which button is pressed?

Tags: ios, email, button

I have an app that is for 3 different offices and I would like to be able to choose which office the resulting collated data will be sent to via an email. I would like to use a different button for each of the offices that will automatically populate an email recipient and then a final button at the end will collate all the information and attach it all to an email. Is there any way of doing this? I have the send button figured out, its the populating the recipient that I can't work out.

Here is the email part that I have but is populated by 1 email address rather than depending on a button press at the moment.

```
    - (IBAction)checkData:(id)sender
{




    unsigned int x,a = 0;
    NSMutableString *emailmessage;
    emailmessage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @""];

    for (x=0; x<9; x++)
    {
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                if (nameTextField.text == nil) {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Name, "];
                    a=1;

                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (emailTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email Address, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (dateLabel.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Date and Time of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;


            case 3:
                if (locationTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Location of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                if (locLabel.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"GPS Location, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                if (observersTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Observers Team, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if (affectedTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Affected Team, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (catLabel.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Rating Classification, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                if (onOffLabel.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Third Party?, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                if (mlabelcategory.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Category, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 10:
                if (messageTextView.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Observation Description, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 11:
                if (activityTextView.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Type of Work Activity, "];
                    a=1;
                }

                break;
            case 12:
                if (imageView.image == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Image, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }


    }



    {
        name = nameTextField.text;
        emailaddress = emailTextField.text;
        date = dateLabel.text;

        location = locationTypeBtn.text;
        observers = originatorTypeBtn.text;
        affected = destinationTypeBtn.text;
        rating = catLabel.text;
        thirdparty = onOffLabel.text;
        category = categoryTypeBtn.text;
        message = messageTextView.text;
        activity = activityTextView.text;
        gps = locLabel.text;




        NSMutableString *nearmissreport;
        nearmissreport = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<br><br> <b>Name:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Date & Time of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Location of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>GPS Location:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Observers Team:</b> %@ <br> <b>Affected Team:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Rating Classification:</b> %@ <br><br> %@ <br><br> <b>Category:</b> %@ <br><b>Observation Description:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Type of Work Activity:</b> %@ <br><br><b>Image:</b><br>", name, emailaddress, date, location, gps, observers, affected, rating, thirdparty, category, message, activity];

        NSLog(@"Near Miss Report: %@", nearmissreport);

        NSMutableString *testoMail;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: nearmissreport];

        NSLog(@"%@", testoMail);


        //MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        MFMailComposeViewController  *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController  alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject: rating];

        // Set up the recipients.
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"example@example.com",nil];

        //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
        //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
        //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

        // Attach an image to the email.

        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([imageView image]);
        [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"NearMiss"];

        // Fill out the email body text.
        //NSMutableString *emailBody;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", testoMail];

        [picker setMessageBody:testoMail isHTML:YES]; //HTML!!!!!!

        // Present the mail composition interface.
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}


// The mail compose view controller delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Use `button.tag` to identify which button is pressed . :)

Comment: Hi @AbhishekBedi i dont suppose you know of any good examples that you can point me in the direction of that will teach me how to use button.tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459570/how-do-i-set-and-get-uibuttons-tag

Comment: I can't see how the button.tag would be able to populate the recipient email?

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement the method that's called when your button is pressed, parse out the id of the button from the info that was passed in, and then set the "to" field of the email accordingly?

Comment: So if for example when the button was pressed it populate a LabelA with the email address and then instead of example@example.com have it looking at LabelA?

Comment: I thought you were trying to make a MFMail compose dialog. Can you explain a little bit more what you mean by this talk of a "labelA"?

Comment: Sorry what I was thinking is if when the button is pressed it populates a label, for example LabelA, I can then use the result in LabelA to populate the email recipient? For example if button that says "Office 1" is pressed the label will populate with email address example1@example.com if "Office 2" button is pressed the label will populate with example2@example.com. Or is this a really long winded way of doing it?

Comment: Your 99% there, Your problem is you don't know how to identify which button was pressed. There are at least 4 ways that I can think of. My question would be are the 3 buttons properties? do they have names like emailBossButton? The other thing to work out is are all the buttons pointing to the same IBAction? Another question, where is the code you show called? in the IBAction method?

Comment: There's no need to go through the intermediary step of populating a label. I would hook up all three buttons to the same IB action and then have a switch statement that populates the to field of the MFMailComposer depending on the id of the button that was pressed. From this IB action you'll be able to present the MFMail vc.

Comment: @latenitecoder The code is shown in the IBAction method. When the Send Email button is pressed it grabs all this information and populates an email. I'm struggling to add anything other than a straight forward email address to the *toRecipients line at the moment. I thought I would test it with 'name' for example but it just comes up blank.

Comment: Paul your not really making sense now. If you have an IBAction with your composer working you just need to point all three buttons to that IBAction. Either in interface builder or programatically set the buttons tag property to be unique (0,1,2 maybe?) then follow the code shown above from Abhishek Bedi - It's as clear as I can make it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);
switch(button.tag) {
case 1 :
// set label.text = example1@example.com
break;
case 2 :
// set label.text = example2@example.com
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm completely lost now. Is it possible to add my code to this to show what I put into the *toRecipients to get this working? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {
    NSMutableString *report = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<br><br> <b>Name:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Date & Time of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Location of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>GPS Location:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Observers Team:</b> %@ <br> <b>Affected Team:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Rating Classification:</b> %@ <br><br> %@ <br><br> <b>Category:</b> %@ <br><b>Observation Description:</b> %@ <br><br> <b>Type of Work Activity:</b> %@ <br><br><b>Image:</b><br>", name, emailaddress, date, location, gps, observers, affected, rating, thirdparty, category, message, activity];
    NSLog(@"Near Miss Report: %@", report);

    NSMutableString *testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:report];
    NSLog(@"%@", testoMail);

    MFMailComposeViewController  *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController  alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject: rating];

    // Set up the recipients.
    NSArray *toRecipients;
    NSArray *ccRecipients;
    NSArray *bccRecipients;

    switch([sender tag]) {
        case 0 : {
            // set label.text = example1@example.com
            toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"example@example.com",nil];
            ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
            bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];
            break;
        }
        case 1 : {
            // set label.text = example2@example.com
            toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"example@example.com",nil];
            ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
            bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];
            break;
        }
        case 2 : {
            // set label.text = example2@example.com
            toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"example@example.com",nil];
            ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
            bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];
            break;
    }
}
    if(toRecipients.length >0) {
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
}

if(ccRecipients.length >0) {
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
}

if(bccRecipients.length >0) {
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];
}

// Attach an image to the email.
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([imageView image]);
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"NearMiss"];

// Fill out the email body text.
//NSMutableString *emailBody;
testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", testoMail];

[picker setMessageBody:testoMail isHTML:YES]; //HTML!!!!!!

// Present the mail composition interface.
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing this will send to whichever recipient depending what button you push? What I am trying to achieve is the selection of the email recipient is done as a separate action to sending the email. So maybe at the top of the app you push Button A for which office you work in, fill in the rest of the app fields and then at the bottom you have your separate send button that will take all the information you have just input and attach it to an email. Can I achieve that with this code? Many Thanks

Comment: I've re-worded my initial question with the full email code so hopefully its clearer. I don't think i was clear on what I was after last time, sorry about that.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how strong your coding is but you could copy and paste parts of my answer into your methods.

1] create a string class property to hold the email address(ess)
2] create a method that populates that string property (using the switch statement)
3] create a method that uses the string property as the recipient array and send the email

Everything you need is in the examples I and others have written here. If you want to separate out setting the recipients, just create a method to do that alone. Any help?