# How to fill a textfield with appropiate username based on avatar selection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have constructed the following method `fetchLastFiveLogins` and the method successfully adds the users avatar to the `_avatarButton`.  However, when a user taps the avatar it calls the `fillUserName` method.  That part is working, but I can't figure out how to fill the `_textfieldUsername` with the username associated with the avatar.  Below is a snippet of the `fetchLastFiveLogins` method.

```
// sort / filter "results" to display the last five "lastLogin(s)"
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastLogin" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [request setFetchLimit:5];

    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //     fetch records and handle error
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!results) {
        // handle error
        // also if there is login data handle error so app doesn't crash
    }
    Account *anAccount;

    // create a stock image
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HomeBrewPoster1.jpg"];

    NSMutableArray *avatars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
    for ( anAccount in results) {
        NSLog(@"results%@",anAccount.lastLogin);
        if(anAccount.lastLogin) {
            NSLog(@"anAccount.lastLogin = %@, by:%@",anAccount.lastLogin,anAccount.username);
            if (anAccount.avatar != nil) {
                UIImage *avatarImg = [UIImage imageWithData:anAccount.avatar ];
                [avatars addObject:avatarImg];
            }
            else {
                [avatars addObject:btnImage];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"avatars array%lu",(unsigned long)avatars.count);
    for ( NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // Check that we have enough logins
        if (i < results.count) {
            NSLog(@"avatars =%@",avatars[i]);

            CGFloat staticX = 0;
            CGFloat staticWidth = 80;
            CGFloat staticHeight = 80;
            CGFloat staticPadding = 5;

            _avatarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

            // the last two values control the size of the button
            _avatarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
            [_avatarButton setFrame:CGRectMake((staticX + (i * (staticHeight + staticPadding))),5,staticWidth,staticHeight)];

            // make corners round
            _avatarButton.layer.cornerRadius = 40; // value varies -- // 35 yields a pretty good circle.
            _avatarButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

            // assign method / action to button
            [_avatarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fillUserName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

            [_avatarButton setBackgroundImage:[avatars objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSLog(@"avatarImage = %@",[_avatarButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
            [_avatarScroll addSubview:_avatarButton];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: avatars array does not contain lastLogin and username. How can you access those without having them in avatars array ?

Comment: @harshayarabarla the `results` array contains the `lastLogin`, `username`, and `avatar` attributes from the Core Data datamodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Make the `fillUserName` method take the parameter `fillUserName:(id) sender`, so that the method will be passed the button that was pressed. You'll want to tweak the addTarget so that it uses `@selector(fillUserName:)` (with the colon at the end).

**Step 2:** You'll need to be able to distinguish which of the buttons was pressed. Often people use the `tag` property of UIButton (and other controls) to distinguish the buttons. If you set the tag to be the array index of the result, then the button with tag 0 is the 0th entry in your results array. See this question: [How do i set and get UIButtons' tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459570/how-do-i-set-and-get-uibuttons-tag) for some code samples.

**Step 3:** Ensure that you've held on to references to the results array, so that you can access it from the `fillUserName:` method.

Update: As I mention in my comment, below, a solution that makes use of blocks seems like a much better solution, and some folks have written some [nice code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908003/uibutton-block-equivalent-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents-method) to enable that.

Comment: I confess that I've never really loved this heuristic in Objective-C. But your question motivated me to find this answer, which was interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908003/uibutton-block-equivalent-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents-method